# Mistakenly changed the Private IP Address

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, windows-server-2012-r2, azure

I had deployed an Virtual Machine with Windows Server 2012 R2.

I went to

```
"Network and Sharing Settings" ->
"Change Adapter Settings" ->
"Ethernet/Properties" ->
"Internet Protocol Version 4/Properties"
```

And by mistake changed the IP Address to a value different than the Private IP Address. Now I am not able to connect to the VM using RDP and also the website deployed is not working.

Answer (score 1):

A few solutions:

1. Create another VM on the same Virtual Network and try to connect to it using the IP you manually configured
2. Changing the size of the VM will reset the network because it's redeployed to a new cluster
3. Navigate to your VM, All Settings, Check Health or Troubleshoot and follow the guide "troubleshooting RDP connections"

Answer (score 0):

If you changed a setting and it broke, change it back. Login to the Windows Server 2012, open Hyper-V, connect to the VM and change the IP. If you want to use the new IP address then update your DNS records.